# Solr boost query syntax

Tags: solr

The [Solr function query documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#exists) says:

`exists(query({!v='year:2012'}))` will return `true` for docs with `year`=2012

I have a document like:

```
{
  id: 1,
  user_type: ADMIN,
  like_score: 1
}
```

`id`, `user_type` and `like_score` are all indexed and stored files, with `id` being int, `user_type` being string and `like_score` being int.

I issue a query like this:

```
q={!boost b=if(true,10,1)}id:1&rows=1&fl=*,score
```

which works. But this query does not work:

```
q={!boost b=if(exists(query({!v='user_type:ADMIN'})),10,1)}id:1&rows=1&fl=*,score
```

It gives an error like this:

```
"error":{
  "msg":"org.apache.solr.search.SyntaxError: Cannot parse ')),5,10)}id:1': Encountered \" \")\" \") \"\" at line 1, column 0.\nWas expecting one of:\n    <NOT> ...\n    \"+\" ...\n    \"-\" ...\n    <BAREOPER> ...\n    \"(\" ...\n    \"*\" ...\n    <QUOTED> ...\n    <TERM> ...\n    <PREFIXTERM> ...\n    <WILDTERM> ...\n    <REGEXPTERM> ...\n    \"[\" ...\n    \"{\" ...\n    <LPARAMS> ...\n    <NUMBER> ...\n    <TERM> ...\n    \"*\" ...\n    ",
  "code":400
}
```

How do I fix the query?

This syntax works:

```
q={!func}if(exists(query({!v='user_type:ADMIN'})),5,10)&rows=1&fl=*,score
```

but it doesn't do what I want to the score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asked solr-user group. Here is answer from Chris Hostetter:

The problem is the way you are trying to nest queries inside of each other
w/o any sort of quoting -- the parser has no indication that the "b" param
is `if(exists(query({!v='user_type:ADMIN'})),10,1)` it thinks it's
`"if(exists(query({!v='user_type:ADMIN'"` and the rest is confusing it.

If you quote the "b" param to the boost parser, then it should work...

`http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q={!boost b="if(exists(query({!v='foo_s:ADMIN'})),10,1)"}id:1`

...or if you could use variable derefrencing, either of these should
work...

`http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q={!boost b=$b}id:1&b=if(exists(query({!v='foo_s:ADMIN'})),10,1)`

`http://localhost:8983/solr/select?q={!boost b=if(exists(query($nestedq)),10,1)}id:1&nestedq=foo_s:ADMIN`

-Hoss